# Datatables with rowGrouping unable to hide columns

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, datatable

The JS:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
//  $( "#dashboard_container" ).tabs();
    $('#listings').dataTable({
                                "bRetrieve": true,
                                "aoColumns":
                                [
                                    { "bVisible": false },
                                    { "bVisible": false },
                                    { "bVisible": false },
                                    { "bVisible": false },
                                    { "bVisible": false },
                                    { "bVisible": false },
                                    { "bVisible": false },
                                    { "bVisible": false },
                                    { "bVisible": false },
                                ]
    }).rowGrouping({
            iGroupingColumnIndex: 1,
            sGroupingColumnSortDirection: "asc",
            iGroupingOrderByColumnIndex: 0,
            bExpandableGrouping: true, 
            bExpandSingleGroup: true,
            iExpandGroupOffset: -1
    });
});
```

The HTML:

```
    <table class="datatable" id="listings">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Group Index</th><th>Group Display Name</th>
            <th>Organization</th>
            <th>Volumes</th>
            <th>Read (MB/s)</th>
            <th>Write (MB/s)</th>
            <th>Volume Size (GB)</th>
            <th>My Cost (USD)</th>
            <th>Comments</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tfoot></tfoot>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>0</td><td><a href="/dashboard/" class="orglist_group_link">Artful Scientific</a></td>
            <td>Something Co.</td>
            <td><a href="/details/view?volume=12345678" class="orglist_link">information</a></td>
            <td>0</td>
            <td>0</td>
            <td>0</td>
            <td>$0</td>
            <td><a class="btn small icon i_preview comment_edit_button" rel="1" title="edit or view comment">View</a></td>
        </tr>
           </tbody>
        </table>
     </div>
```

The problem:

I am able to successfully do the row groupings and it works fine, however I have a need where I need to hide 2 of the columns to certain roles. As well as hide an additional column which would be the Equivlent of the "Organization" column which the grouping uses. However from the above JS you can see I have tried hiding all columns just to see if any would actually hide in my last ditch effort before coming here. No matter which ones all or one none will hide. Anyone know a work around for this? As I need the columns to remain but hidden to the actual view

Comment: What version of dataTables are you using?

Comment: 1.9, however I did find my answer, and maybe I should answer my own question here to prevent confusion. Base line is, I had bought a ready made template, of which had datatables included. However with the issues I was having from not being able to work with datatables as I am used to or should have been able to I started poking deep into the templates files, and low and behold I found a sigle call to `$.dataTable();` in a context that would pick up on all tables, and make a call on them before my scripts would.

Comment: very poor design in aspect of scalability, but once i found that I removed it from the base, and things started working very smooth from there on.

Comment: Damn, didn't see your comments until after I finished making a jsFiddle of the above showing it working fine. :/ - http://jsfiddle.net/trapper/fYaYW/

Comment: Yes, please do answer your own question and accept it, thanks. You might even get some up-votes for it :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

hide column using this command and first parameter is index of the column and
second parameter is visibilty

fnSetColumnVis( 1, false );